# Sending percent encoding as part of data

Tags: php, urlencode

I have a site where anyone can leave comments.
By leaving a comment browser makes an ajax request to PHP script, sending `encodeURIComponent`-ed data to PHP script.
Earlier, in the PHP script, I added

```
$data = str_replace("\n","\\n",str_replace("\"","\\\"",$_POST["text"]));
```

Now I’ve been testing by inputting random stuff and found an exploit: if to input `%00`, it will be added to my comments file as null-terminator and corrupts my data. Also, other percent-encoded value will be decoded.

I am sending data as a regular  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

How to fix that?

Comment: Use a real database instead of a text file.

Comment: Base64 encode everything? Do you care about XSS or anything else, too?

Comment: I think the problem is in php and not proper work with encoding from my side.

Comment: @ChrisHaas sounds bad. Maybe just ban %00?

Comment: Can you remove `$_POST` from the equation completely by replacing it with a string literal that breaks your code, and also include your file reading and writing logic?

Comment: In my experience, it is often the case that complex attacks can be fixed with simple logic, and simple attacks can be fixed by more complex logic, but it is usually rare that simple attacks can be defeated with simple logic. To your issue, banning the single `%00` might fix that single attack but there might be other variants like `%\n00` or something that could still be a problem. (I'm not saying that one is, I just made it up). When dealing with strings, the encoding (JavaScript, HTTP, PHP) can be really surprising at times.

Comment: @ChrisHaas added as an answer

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution I’ve made so far is:

```
$_POST["text"] = str_replace("\"","\\\"",$_POST["text"]);

for($i=0;$i<=40;$i++)
 if(chr($i)!="\n"&&chr($i)!="\r"&&chr($i)!=" "&&chr($i)!="("&&chr($i)!="&"&&chr($i)!="!"&&chr($i)!="\""&&chr($i)!="'")
   $_POST["text"] = str_replace(chr($i),"",$_POST["text"]);

   $_POST["text"] = str_replace("\\","",$_POST["text"]);
```

It just removes all special and potentially malware non-readable characters with some exceptions (newlines, ampersands etc.).

The only issue of this solution is that it removes backslash (but successfully writes data).

Comment: Because you aren't using braces `{}` for your `for` or `if` statements, the bottom line of text will always run. That may be what you wanted, but I'm just noting it because the indentation implies that it should be grouped. I would also think a `foreach` loop would be much more readable. `foreach (["\n", "\r", " ", "(", "&", "!", "\"", "'"] as $c) { $_POST["text"] = str_replace($c, "", $_POST["text"]); }`